# One of 3 phone numbers as requiredValidator

Tags: asp.net, validation, dynamic, contact-form, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to dynamically create a table that is for contact information. I have it set that you type your name, pick relationship to client, then fill 3 phone numbers. When adding a new Row I was making it so that it required that at least one of the numbers was filled in. Once this is done then you can add a new contact.

I am doing this in VB.Net, and hoping someone would be able to help.

Before looking at the code I wanted to mention that I have a bunch of lines already commented out. Just for some context behind the code I have tried a multitude of ways and am not really sure if I am on the correct path. Anyway here is the chunk of code where I do my dynamic validations.

```
        tCell = New TableCell
        tCell.CssClass = "dynamicTCell"
        tCell.Controls.Add(tDrop)
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
        tCell.Controls.Add(conRowRequired)

        tBoxHome = New TextBox
        tBoxHome.ID = "con" + conRows.ToString + "HomePhone"
        'tBoxHome.ValidationGroup = "conPhoneNumbers" + conRows.ToString
        'tBoxHome.CausesValidation = True

        conRowRequiredHome = New RequiredFieldValidator
        'conRowRequiredHome = New CustomValidator
        'conRowRequiredHome.ClientValidationFunction = "ServerValidation"
        conRowRequiredHome.ID = "conHomePhoneRequired" + conRows.ToString
        'AddHandler conRowRequiredHome.ServerValidate, AddressOf ServerValidation

        'tBoxHome = conTable.FindControl("con" + conRows.ToString + "HomePhone")
        conRowRequiredHome.ControlToValidate = tBoxHome.ID
        'conRowRequiredHome.ValidationGroup = "conPhoneNumbers"
        conRowRequiredHome.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic
        conRowRequiredHome.ErrorMessage = "*"

        tCell = New TableCell
        tCell.CssClass = "dynamicTCell"
        tCell.Controls.Add(tBoxHome)
        tCell.Controls.Add(conRowRequiredHome)

        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
        'conRowRequiredHome.IsValid = False

        tBoxWork = New TextBox
        tBoxWork.ID = "con" + conRows.ToString + "WorkPhone"
        'tBoxWork.ValidationGroup = "conPhoneNumbers" + conRows.ToString
        'tBoxWork.CausesValidation = True

        'conRowRequiredWork = New CustomValidator
        conRowRequiredWork = New RequiredFieldValidator
        'conRowRequiredWork.ClientValidationFunction = "ServerValidation"
        conRowRequiredWork.ID = "conWorkPhoneRequired" + conRows.ToString
        'tBoxWork = conTable.FindControl("con" + conRows.ToString + "WorkPhone")
        conRowRequiredWork.ControlToValidate = tBoxWork.ID
        'conRowRequiredWork.ValidationGroup = "conPhoneNumbers"
        conRowRequiredWork.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic
        conRowRequiredWork.ErrorMessage = "*"

        tCell = New TableCell
        tCell.CssClass = "dynamicTCell"
        tCell.Controls.Add(tBoxWork)
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
        'conRowRequiredWork.IsValid = False
        tCell.Controls.Add(conRowRequiredWork)

        tBoxCell = New TextBox
        tBoxCell.ID = "con" + conRows.ToString + "CellPhone"
        'tBoxCell.ValidationGroup = "conPhoneNumbers" + conRows.ToString
        ' tBoxCell.CausesValidation = True


        conRowRequiredCell = New RequiredFieldValidator
        'conRowRequiredCell = New CustomValidator
        'conRowRequiredCell.ClientValidationFunction = "ServerValidation"
        conRowRequiredCell.ID = "conCellPhoneRequired" + conRows.ToString
        'tBoxCell = conTable.FindControl("con" + conRows.ToString + "CellPhone")
        conRowRequiredCell.ControlToValidate = tBoxCell.ID
        'conRowRequiredCell.OnServerValidate = "ServerValidation"
        'conRowRequiredCell.ValidationGroup = "conPhoneNumbers"
        conRowRequiredCell.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic
        conRowRequiredCell.ErrorMessage = "*"


        tCell = New TableCell
        tCell.CssClass = "dynamicTextBoxBRRounded"
        tCell.Controls.Add(tBoxCell)
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
        tCell.Controls.Add(conRowRequiredCell)

        'Dim flag As Boolean
        'If tBoxWork IsNot Nothing AndAlso tBoxCell IsNot Nothing AndAlso tBoxHome IsNot Nothing Then
        '    'If (tBoxHome.Text = "" And tBoxWork.Text = "" And tBoxCell.Text = "") Then
        '    'args.IsValid = False
        '    If (tBoxHome.Text <> "" OrElse tBoxCell.Text <> "" OrElse tBoxWork.Text <> "") Then
        '        flag = True
        '    End If
        'End If
```

And the function that I was using for my attempt at conRoeRequiredCell.ClientValidationFunction = "ServerValidation" is shown below. I know it says Sub Class but I have also tried it as a function to no prevail.

```
    'Protected Sub ServerValidation(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
'    args.IsValid = False

'    Dim conTable As Table = DirectCast(PlaceHolderSiblings.FindControl("conTable"), Table)

'    Dim tBoxWork As TextBox = conTable.FindControl("cony" + Session("conRows").ToString + "WorkPhone")
'    Dim tBoxCell As TextBox = conTable.FindControl("con" + Session("conRows").ToString + "CellPhone")
'    Dim tBoxHome As TextBox = conTable.FindControl("con" + Session("conRows").ToString + "HomePhone")

'    If tBoxWork IsNot Nothing AndAlso tBoxCell IsNot Nothing AndAlso tBoxHome IsNot Nothing Then
'        'If (tBoxHome.Text = "" And tBoxWork.Text = "" And tBoxCell.Text = "") Then
'        'args.IsValid = False
'        If (tBoxHome.Text <> "" OrElse tBoxCell.Text <> "" OrElse tBoxWork.Text <> "") Then
'            args.IsValid = True
'        End If
'    End If
'End Sub
```

If this is sloppy, just let me know how/what to do to fix it and I will. I am still somewhat a rookie when it comes to Visual Basic and StackOverFlow seeing this is my first post. I expect I am missing a few lines of code that will help make sense of this, so any question ask away and I'll respond as quickly as possible.

Comment: We don't write code, we just (maybe) try help code that you've already written.

Comment: Sorry for that. This is my first time doing this. I'll edit the original post to include a snippet of the code

Comment: @MarcB have edited the question/post. Hopefully that helps. I know I've said this a lot but if I forgot or did something wrong let me know so I can fix them